# How can I stop foreach loop iteration until methods result in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array() `lenght=13` which I am using in `foreach`

```
$games = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13);
foreach($games as $game_id){
    $this->insertTrainingData($game_id, 'advance', 5);
    $this->insertTrainingData($game_id, 'intermediate', 4);
    $this->insertTrainingData($game_id, 'easy', 3);            
}
```

The above foreach loop passes each game_id into `insertTrainingData()` for `game_id` insertion based on certain validations.

`insertTrainingData()` is validating each `game_id` before inserting the record, if all goes well then function store game_id for particular group (`advance`, `intermediate`, `easy`).

**What is problem that I am facing?**

It is when foreach loop passes game_id to three times called `insertTrainingData()` method in single iteration and jump into next iteration then same process. I am thinking on next iteration foreach loop passes game_id before completion of previous iteration job `(insertTrainingData())`.

So is this possible if I can stop foreach loop iteration until all functions return final result and then let foreach loop on next iteration. That's what I am thinking, not sure if I am wrong.

Here is function which decides to insert game_id for particular group based on validations.

```
private function insertTrainingData($game_id, $type, $limit){
    $error = 0;
    $result = true;
    $todayTraining = Training::whereRaw("Date(created_at)=Curdate() and type='".$type."'")->get();
    if($todayTraining->count() === $limit ){
        $error = 1;
        $result = false;
    }

    $todayExist = Training::whereRaw("Date(created_at)=Curdate() and game_id=$game_id")->get();

    if($todayExist->count() > 0 || $todayExist->first() !== null){
        $error = 1;
        $result = false;
    }

    $recordInTwoRowDays = Training::whereRaw("created_at >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) and game_id=$game_id and type='".$type."'")->get();
    if($recordInTwoRowDays->count() > 0 ){
        $error = 1;
        $result = false;
    }

    if($error === 0){
        $AddTraining           = new Training;
        $AddTraining->game_id    = $game_id;
        $AddTraining->type       = $type;
        $AddTraining->save();
        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**What happened when I executed above script?**

Actually the above script added 6 rows for `advance` group however you can see the `limit` is `5`

Can someone kindly guide me about it, I  would really appreciate.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Use transactions.

Comment: @BenM appreciate your interest, can you explain bit please.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: PHP is synchronous. Next iteration won't happen before the previous iteration is done.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Actually the above script added 6 rows for `advance` group however you can see the `limit` is 5

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that PHP is synchronous. If you call a function, it won't continue to the next line in your code until the first function is done. That's simply how PHP works. If you have some issue, it's not because one call is made before the previous call is finished executing.

Comment: If you post the full code of the `insertTrainingData()`-method, we might be able to help though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sure, I have edited my question, now full script is available. Appreciate

Comment: I can't see any wrong in your code, can you check is there any place is using func insertTrainingData() too?? Do you truncate your table before run this loop?

Comment: @Momo Yes, I did lot of times but could not figure out why it is happening.

Comment: @AyazShah do you want to stop the loop and any further operation after failure in any of the 3 operations? Does that failure also involve a rollback in the database that  you would like to have?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes that's what I wanted that next iteration should happen just completion of three methods and there is not rollback involve.

Comment: Well, they do happen synchronously only. Maybe you mean `$this->insertTrainingData($game_id, 'advance', 5) &&  $this->insertTrainingData($game_id, 'intermediate', 4) && $this->insertTrainingData($game_id, 'easy', 3);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and it should not insert the 6th rows, maybe you are looking on wrong place, however, here is the code that you can improve:

1. It will not go for other if statement when the first statement is
   false
2. Hence it will not call for second SQL statement
3. ->count() is way much better than ->get()->count()

.

```
private function insertTrainingData($game_id, $type, $limit) {
    $todayTraining = Training::whereRaw("Date(created_at)=Curdate() and type='".$type."'")->count();
    if ($todayTraining >= $limit ) {
        return false;
    }

    $todayExist = Training::whereRaw("Date(created_at)=Curdate() and game_id=$game_id")->count();
    if ($todayExist > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $recordInTwoRowDays = Training::whereRaw("created_at >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) and game_id=$game_id and type='".$type."'")->count();
    if ($recordInTwoRowDays > 0 ) {
        return false;
    }

    $addTraining = new Training();
    $addTraining->game_id = $game_id;
    $addTraining->type = $type;
    $addTraining->save();
    return true;
}
```